# Weave external aspect with new pointcut

Tags: java, external, aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm pretty new to AOP in general, but I have the following problem.

I have 2 projects. One containing an aspect that does some performance testing and another project which has a dependency to the previous one.

What I'd like to achieve is weave the aspect from project 1, into another aspect of project 2. As such doing some performance testing on the aspect of project 2.

I found out it's not possible with Spring-AOP, but it should be possible with AspectJ's weaving. However, I did not figure out how.

Im pretty sure I need to make use of the [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/index.html), using configuration as listed in the [AspectJ documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#enabling-load-time-weaving). But nothing seems to be picked up? Any pointers on how to write an extra pointcut for an external aspect?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use aspectj-maven-plugin, instead i use load-time-weaving and it works fine.

are you gonna use aspectj language to define your aspects? if not, i suggest load-time-weaving

Answer (score 0):

It would have been a good idea to post your relevant maven pom.xml fragments, without that, I can only have a guess at your problem: did you specify your *project 1* dependency as an **aspect library** in your aspectj-maven-plugin configuration in your pom.xml? Example taken from the [aspectj-maven-plugin documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/libraryJars.html) and modified:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>group.id.of.project.1</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact.id.of.project.1</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You'll also need the dependency on your classpath too, but I guess you have that already.