# AspectJ weaving from dependency not applying to project

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspectj, aspect

I have a Java 8 Maven project that defines a custom annotation and an aspect.  When running test code in that project itself, it is applying the aspect to the annotated classes.  I am then packaging and installing project.

I then bring in that dependency into a new project (non-Spring).  The new project is then not having the aspect applied to it's classes, though it does bring in the new annotation.

How do I have a single JAR to define an annotation and aspect and have it applied to all of my  projects with Maven?

Comment: Do you have compile time weaving enabled in your new project's build process? Or do you have load-time weaving enabled when you run your new project?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete I am trying compile time, the same as the original project containing the aspect itself.  That project compiles and executes the aspects fine.  I have the same build plugin configured on the project bringing in the aspect as a dependency, but the aspects are not being applied.

Comment: Build configuration is not necessarily trivial, so please add the relevant build configuration to your question.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete Do you know of any examples out there where the aspect used for a build is brought in as a dependency?  I feel it is a common use case, I just have been unable to search for either instructions or examples on how to weave an aspect from a dependency.

Comment: Here's an [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023217/2699901) I made earlier to an unrelated question, but it could be useful for you because it contains an example on how to specify aspect libraries in a maven build.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete  Thank you very much! Configuring aspectLibraries was the answer.  If you copy-paste your referenced info here I'll mark it as the answer.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify your aspect project dependency as an **aspect library** in your aspectj-maven-plugin configuration in your pom.xml. Let's suppose your aspect module has the groupid:artifactid `groupid:aspect-module`. Your `pom.xml` should look similar to this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspect-module</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>groupid</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspect-module</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note that I'm switching off the `maven-compiler-plugin` because they tend do overwrite each other's output with the `aspectj-maven-plugin`, and the AspectJ compiler should be able to compile normal java files and weave them in the same step anyway, so using the maven-compiler-plugin is redundant. If you are using Eclipse + AJDT, this maven configuration will much better reflect what happens in your IDE while you're developing.